# Can I hide SMS on Android?

Tags: java, android

I would like to develop an application for Android 3.0 with only one button...
When I click on this button I should HIDE all the SMS sent from a specific phone number.

Is it possible?

Comment: A Tiger Woods App you mean ? :P

Comment: But then you should hide the Hide button, otherwise it's obvious, that something is hidden - don't understimate your girl friends intellectual power :P

Comment: @Andreas_D I only would know how to do it...I don't have to hide nothing :-D

Comment: There is no documented and supported API in the Android SDK for dealing with saved SMS messages.

Answer (score 2):

Yea u can hide the Receiving SMS from the particular Number

Just paste the code in your receiving broadcast receiver class

```
if (senderphonenumber != null && senderphonenumber.equals("9400000000")) {
                    // Process our sms...
                    abortBroadcast();
                }
```

In your Manifest File put these code, and set a higher value for android priority

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsFilter">
    <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Also don't forget to give the necessary permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either delete these SMS (and save them to file etc.) or replace Messaging app with your own.

Comment: is there not a parameter on the DB Like visible true/false ?

Comment: @Damiano - guessing without knowing: no, there's no such parameter, because it's not a common use case to *hide* (blacklist) SMS on database level and I've never seen such a feature on any device.

Comment: @Andreas_D  ok so...I only can remove them from DB and save it on a SECRET file. right?